# Webform Build Tab not displaying correctly

Tags: webforms

We just installed the Webform module, but as I'm going in to create and edit a new form, the "Build" tab is only allowing me to enter Elements with YAML code (pic one below). In the module description, it shows a preview of the Form Builder (pic two below), which doesn't look anything like what we have.

Is there an add-in that makes it looks like the module description...and therefore easier to use?

[image: Pic One - My Build Tab screenshot]
[image: Pic Two - Module Description screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Webform UI module.